# O que é SQL? Como usar?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Eu já sei ao menos que SQL tem relação com banco de dados, com a consulta de valores em banco de dados.

Mas não está claro *o que seria* o SQL. Para que utilizaria este recurso? E como se usa o SQL, por exemplo em um sistema de usuários?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Basicamente básico

As informações que eu estou postando aqui são básicas e podem conter erros, qualquer coisa podem editar a resposta ou comentar ;)

### Breve explicação

SQL é uma linguagem para banco de dados, ela possui uma sintaxe parecida com a do inglês, se eu fosse por exemplo consultar o **Nome** do usuário com **ID 2** eu poderia ter uma tabela assim:

```
+----+------------------+
| ID | Nome             |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | João Vitor       |
| 2  | Isabela Monteiro |
| 3  | John Snow        |
+----+------------------+
```

Eu diria para o servidor SQL executar o seguinte comando no banco de dados:

```
SELECT Nome FROM `nomeDaTabela` WHERE `ID` = 2;
```

Que traduzindo, seria:

SELECIONAR A COLUNA `Nome` DA TABELA `nomeDaTabela` ONDE O ID FOR = 2

Assim eu selecionaria: **Isabela Monteiro**

Claro, eu posso fazer muito mais do que ler informações, eu posso inseri-las, atualizá-las, deletá-las, uni-las e muito mais.

O SQL em si é apenas uma sintaxe, existem vários tipos de servidores que interpretam SQL, os mais famosos são o MySQL, o Postgre e o MS SQL (Windows/Microsoft). Algumas funções e parte da sintaxe podem variar de servidor para servidor, mas a essência é a mesma.

Basicamente o esquema seria:

```
Meu código -> Declaração SQL (SELECT * FROM blabla) -> Servidor (MySQL)
-> Servidor interpreta e salva no banco de dados
```

Existem várias utilidades nisso, mas como o nome já diz, o objetivo principal é armazenar dados em tabelas no bancos de dados.

## Exemplo do login

Vamos supor que eu precise de um login para meu aplicativo, aqui está a minha tabela de usuários:

```
+----+------------------+--------------+
| ID | Nome             | Senha        |
+----+------------------+--------------+
| 1  | João Vitor       | senha1234    |
| 2  | Isabela Monteiro | goLfiNhO0    |
| 3  | John Snow        | uKnowNothing |
+----+------------------+--------------+
```

Agora que já conheço meus usuários, eu preciso do meu sistema básico de login:

Primeiro pegamos a informação que o usuário enviou:

**Nome: *João Vitor***

**Senha: *senha1234***

Agora nós comparamos a informação com a do banco de dados para checarmos se as informações que o usuário do aplicativo enviou estão corretas.

```
SELECT * FROM `tabelaUsuarios` WHERE `Nome`="João Vitor" AND `Senha`="senha1234"
```

O servidor, por padrão, irá retornar o número de linhas da tabela que encontrou com essa condição, se o número de linhas for maior que 0, sabemos que o login realmente existe e o autenticamos. Se não, pedimos ao usuário para digitar as credencias novamente.

## Info básica

Sugiro que cheque http://www.w3schools.com/sql/; está em inglês, mas possui um bom tutorial básico para o que você precisa.

Comment: Como eu utilizaria este recurso em C#.NET?

Answer (score 4):

SQL é a linguagem que vc usa para fazer consultas e inserções em banco de dados relacional. Sua pergunta é bastante básica e te aconselho a estudar o que é Banco de Dados Relacional e tentar entender como ele funciona. SQL não é um recurso mas sim uma linguagem. Existem vários tipos de banco de dados, SQLite, SQLServer, Oracle todos usam a linguagem SQL para fazer as operações.

Links úteis para estudo:
http://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Answer (score 0):

Sistemas Gerenciadores de Banco de Dados foram criados para garantir a persistência, concistência e integridade dos Dados de um Sistema, solução criada por volta dos anos 1970 e vem funcionando bem pelas informações que recebo.